# Check if function has an empty body

Tags: c++

Is it possible to check (at compile or runtime) if function or class method has an an empty body?

E.g

```
void empty_body_function(){}
void non_empty_body_function(){int i;}

int main()
{
    assert(magic(empty_body_function) == true);
    assert(magic(non_empty_body_function) == false);
}
```

P.S.I define non empty body like that: function/method does have non empty body if and only if it has any code(valid C++ code, for sure) inside {} after preprocessing

P.P.S Answering "why" question:
What I'm trying to achieve is to check if particular interface implementation "does nothing". No side effects, no calculations, etc

Comment: Can I ask what problem you are trying t solve with this?

Comment: What exactly is an empty body? Does `/*abc*/` count?

Comment: Not on the C++ language layer. You could maybe do some preprocessing: detect the function signature and then check if only whitespaces are between {}.

Comment: `{int i;}` is empty body IMO. 1 declaration with no side effects, and 0 statements.

Comment: @cigien I will define like that: function/method does have non empty body if and only if it has any code(valid C++ code, for sure) inside {} after preprocessing.

Comment: @Dmitry on the face value, the answer to your question is "NO". However, if you explain the actual problem, a solution to the problem itself might exist.

Comment: @Dmitry I see. I generally don't like focusing on *why* a question wants to do something, but in this case, I think that might be necessary. *code* is not really a good way to think about C++. e.g. a body containing `int i;` is an empty body (as rustyx) pointed out. Perhaps you could ask if a function has any *side-effects*, since that's an *observable* characteristic of a function. There aren't (and shouldn't be) checks for non observable properties of a function.

Comment: @SergeyA 
I'd like to check if particular interface implementation "does nothing". No side effects, no calculations, etc

Comment: That makes much more sense, but then your examples don't really work. Both your functions *do nothing*. Add something like `cout << "hi";` to the second function, or modify a global variable.

Comment: @Dmitry again, what are you planning to do with this information? Imagine those details magically becoming available to you, what would you do with them?

Comment: @Dmitry, please put that last bit about "does nothing" right in the question.  It's critically important.

Comment: @SergeyA I do have an interface for "smart semaphore" object it allows to execute threads in particular order. Also have an instance which "does nothing" (as no semaphore at all). I'd like to check if that "does nothing implementation" is valid.

Comment: A general question about potentially having side effects is a question optimizing compiler is answering. You would not be able to do with C++, but you could if you analyze the source code with a stand-alone tool. This is no small feat.

Comment: A possible solution - define a dummy struct and use it instead of void for the return value of the functions that match. Then use `std::result_of` to get the return type and compare it to the dummy struct.

Comment: Providing an empty body is not how you should have a function that detectably *does nothing*.  You should have a base class that does nothing, and your implementation should *not override* the base implementation.  Then you can easily have what you want.

Comment: @Wyck That's pretty much what I did, but I anyway would like to make sure that "base implementation" actually does nothing.

Comment: Check your compiler or linker reference.  Some compilers, especially those for embedded systems, have a compiler specific method for retrieving the length of a function.  You could place the function into a separate segment, then use compiler specific statements to get the size of the segment.  All depends on your compiler's published capabilities.

Comment: Depending on your toolchain, you may be able to get a disassembly output (e.g. `objdump -d`) or similar and check the given functions against a known pattern of an empty function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to do that. But C++ metaprogramming is complex and it's hard to say about something that it's impossible.

I'll add - in compile time, for any function that is declared but not defined, it's absolutely impossible. The compiler knows nothing about what the function does except for its parameters and return value.

In runtime, you can try to work with the function's pointer and maybe do things, but I'd imagine that anything in that direction will be very dependant on your compiler/linker configuration.

Also, if this question is for a practical use case - I urge you to think about it again. Checking that the function body is empty a weird thing to do.